# Can't convert complex to float

Tags: python

I get an error with this code, I tried many things but it still keeps saying:

> traceback (most recent call last):
>   File, line 7
>   TypeError: can't convert complex to float

This is the code:

```
import math

a = float(input())
x = complex((a**1/3)*math.exp(0)*1j)
y = complex((a**1/3)*math.exp(((2*math.pi)/3)*1j)) 
z = complex((a**1/3)*math.exp(((4*math.pi)/3)*1j))

print(complex(x).real)
print(complex(x).imag)
print(complex(y).real)
print(complex(y).imag)
print(complex(z).real)

print(complex(z).imag)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please properly format your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`math.exp()` doesn't support complex arguments. You want `cmath.exp()`:

```
>>> math.exp(1j)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
>>> cmath.exp(1j)
(0.5403023058681398+0.8414709848078965j)
```

See [`cmath` — Mathematical functions for complex numbers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html).